# joomla: use a plugin from a module (jmapmyldap)

Tags: plugins, joomla, ldap, joomla3.0

In joomla 3.x I have a plugin in order to manage the authentication and the group memebership mapping, it is JMapMyLDAP.
The plugin has a set of parameters that are stored into the configuration, these parameters regulate how the plugin connect to LDAP server, how the LDAP query are generated, how to map the attributes, and so on ...

Now I'm developing a custom module which is intended to grab some more information from LDAP about the current user, that is, it aims to query for some more extended attributes of the corresponding user in the Active Directory (my current LDAP auth backend).

Considering that I've already configured the JMapMyLDAP plugin with the binding account, the base DN,... it would be useful to re-use the configuration and the functionalities of this plugin instead to write again the LDAP basic functions by myself and store again the same configuration somwhere else...

So the question, generically, is : is there a way in a module to call an initialized istance (i.e. with the stored configurration loaded)  of a plugin in order to call its methods directly ?

In my tests, I've successfully imported the plugin with jimport in `default.php` (or also in `helper.php`)

```
<?php 
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
jimport('shmanic.jldap2');
jimport('shmanic.jmapmyldap');
```

but now ?

I need to get an instance of the `plgUserJMapMyLDAP` (that extends `Jplugin`) in order to be able to query my LDAP backend.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question is that
1. You want to trigger a custom function written in your plugin. You can do it using following script.

```
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin(<plugin type>, <plugin name>);
    $Dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    $result = $Dispatcher->trigger('<Event name>', <array of parameter>);
```

The result variable will return you the expected output if any.

2. You want to use existing parameter configured under plugin. So you can access any plugin parameter anywhere using the following script.

   ```
   $plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin(<plugin type>, <plugin name>);
   $params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);
   echo $params->get('param_name','default_value');
   ```